# Having trouble running Netflix on Elementary!

Tags: applications

I am trying to run Netflix on Firefox, it's just not running. No specific error message too. What can be going wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Guys I was able to get the issue resolved from [here](https://silicophilic.com/watch-netflix-on-linux/). It was basically a Drm issue.

Comment: Hi Raul, please accept your own question (it is [ok to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on SO and you make clear to everyone the question has been successfully answered )
You should also improve the answer, I suggest you to use [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659) as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Install electronplayer snap.

```
sudo snap install electronplayer
```

https://snapcraft.io/electronplayer

If you don't have snap support on the system you need to install it first:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

I'm using electronplayer as my daily Netflix player. Just install, run, login and play.